# Why doesn't my update function execute when I reload the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not really a developer, but I'm trying to learn a little bit of react.js. I want to have a section of my website update every few seconds with new content; a photo, header and body.

For some reason I am able to get this working when the page is already rendered and the element cycles through the content correctly, but when I reload the page I get an error the first time the data is supposed to refresh:

> Home.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'innerHTML')
> at updateTestimonial (Home.js:45:1)

This is what that file looks like:

```
import coverphoto from './img/bkg/moss2.jpg';
import chrisphoto from './img/chrisphoto.png';
import quotes from './img/quotes.png'
import quotes2 from './img/quotes2.png'


const Testimonials = props =>{


const testimonial = document.querySelector('.bodystyle');
const logo = document.querySelector('.testimonial-photo');
const username = document.querySelector('.titlestyle2');
const role = document.querySelector('.subtitlestyle');

const testimonials = [
  {
      name: 'Ben Frank',
      position: 'CEO',
      photo: require('./img/chrisphoto.png'),
      text:
          "Test"
  },
  {
      name: 'Jill Cha',
      position: 'Software Engineer',
      photo: require('./img/chrisphoto.png'),
      text:
          'Testimonial1'
  },
  {
      name: 'Adam Niskanen',
      position: 'Data Entry',
      photo: require('./img/chrisphoto.png'),
      text:
          "Testimonial2"
  },
];


  let idx = 1;
  window.onload = function () {
  function updateTestimonial() {
    let { name, position, photo, text } = testimonials[idx];

    testimonial.innerHTML = text;
    logo.src = photo;
    username.innerHTML = name;
    role.innerHTML = position;

    idx++;
    if (idx > testimonials.length - 1) {
        idx = 0;
    }
}
 

setInterval(updateTestimonial, 10000);
}
    return (
<div className="home_main"    style={{ 
      backgroundImage: `url(${coverphoto})`, 
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>
 <div className="home-testimonial-container">
<img className="quotes" src={quotes}/><img className="quotes2" src={quotes2}/>
<div className='testimonial-entry'>
    <img className='testimonial-photo'
     src={chrisphoto}
     ></img>
    <div className='testimonial-text'>
        <h3 className='titlestyle2'>Dan Cho</h3><h3 className="subtitlestyle" style={{fontSize: "10pt"}}>Winner</h3></div>
        <div className='testimonial-body-container'><h3 className="bodystyle" style={{fontStyle:"italic"}}>Hire him</h3>
        </div>
        </div></div>
</div>

);
}
    
export default Testimonials;
```

I thought that maybe the page wasn't able to find the element cause it hadn't loaded yet, so I put that window.onload around it, but it didn't help.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here? Is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of?
Thanks

Comment: your query selectors are still outside of the onload function

Comment: you should not be setting the `innerHTML` of anything inside a React component. And it's very very rare to want to use things like `document.querySelector` either. That's breaking out of React's declarative paradigm - it's easier to just not use React if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

i only know angular but ,try something like this:

```
import coverphoto from './img/bkg/moss2.jpg';
import chrisphoto from './img/chrisphoto.png';
import quotes from './img/quotes.png'
import quotes2 from './img/quotes2.png'


const Testimonials = props =>{

const testimonials = [
  {
      name: 'Ben Frank',
      position: 'CEO',
      photo: require('./img/chrisphoto.png'),
      text:
          "Test"
  },
  {
      name: 'Jill Cha',
      position: 'Software Engineer',
      photo: require('./img/chrisphoto.png'),
      text:
          'Testimonial1'
  },
  {
      name: 'Adam Niskanen',
      position: 'Data Entry',
      photo: require('./img/chrisphoto.png'),
      text:
          "Testimonial2"
  },
];


  let idx = 1;
  let name = testimonials[idx].name;
  let position= testimonials[idx].position;
  let photo= testimonials[idx].photo;
  let text = testimonials[idx].text;

  function updateTestimonial() {
    idx++;        
    if (idx > testimonials.length - 1) {
        idx = 0;
    }

    name = testimonials[idx].name;
    position= testimonials[idx].position;
    photo= testimonials[idx].photo;
    text = testimonials[idx].text; 
}
 

setInterval(updateTestimonial, 10000);
}
    return (
<div className="home_main"    style={{ 
      backgroundImage: `url(${coverphoto})`, 
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}>
 <div className="home-testimonial-container">
<img className="quotes" src={quotes}/><img className="quotes2" src={quotes2}/>
<div className='testimonial-entry'>
    <img className='testimonial-photo'
     src={photo}
     ></img>
    <div className='testimonial-text'>
        <h3 className='titlestyle2'>{name}</h3><h3 className="subtitlestyle" style={{fontSize: "10pt"}}>{role}</h3></div>
        <div className='testimonial-body-container'><h3 className="bodystyle" style={{fontStyle:"italic"}}>{text}</h3>
        </div>
        </div></div>
</div>

);
}
    
export default Testimonials;
```